# Chrome fails with drag and drop after an https php header redirect

Tags: jquery, html, google-chrome, file-upload, drag-and-drop

I have some code.
It works... then I add in a php httpS (secure) header redirect at the top. refresh the code again and now it fails. It just doesn't accept any file as drag and drop. I can clear cache, clear cookies do anything  I want... it will no longer work.

I have to restart chrome with the lines commented out and then it works again. Why ?

```
<?php
//header( "Location: ". 'https://127.0.0.1/blank.htm' );die; /* uncomment this line to make it fail */
// it MUST be a "secure" redirect to make it fail
?>
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">
  <head>
    <meta charset="utf-8">
    <title>blah</title>
    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0">
    <meta name="description" content="TestAuditor testing quality management">
    <meta name="author" content="The TestAuditor Team">

    <link href="CSS/dropzone.css" rel="stylesheet">
  </head>
  <body>
  <div class="span6">
    <div id="dropzone" class="fade well ui-corner-all">Drop files here</div>
  </div>
    <script src="JS/jquery-1.9.0.js"></script>
    <script src="JS/jquery.filedrop.js"></script>
    <script type="text/javascript">
    //-----------------------
    $(document).ready(function ()
    {
    $('#dropzone').show().filedrop(
      {
      fallback_id: '',
      url: 'AnyUploadFileManager.php',
      paramname: 'userfile',
      withCredentials: true,
      allowedfiletypes: [],
      maxfiles: 250,
      maxfilesize: 20,
      drop: function() { },
      uploadFinished: function(i, file, response, time) {alert('done'); },
      beforeSend: function(file, i, done) {done(); }
      });
    });
    //-----------------------
     </script>
  </body>
</html>
```

Comment: Do you see any errors on chrome web-console? Try to edit your links to "https://127.0.0.1/JS/jquery-1.9.0.js" etc... I had the same problem with IE8...

Comment: Update : This was a bug in Chrome. It is now fixed.